# Get free process memory on android

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

How to get the amount of free memory of current running process on android? Or how to get the total amount of memory allocated to current process programmatically?

Method `ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()` doesn't work in my case because it returns free SYSTEM memory, but not the process memory. There's also `ActivityManager.getProcessInfo()` method but it returns an old API struct and I don't know whether it's possible to retrieve amount of free memory using that data.

Any explanations on that methods or maybe some other ways to get the amount of free memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();` which returns the maximum heap size for your process in bytes.

Althoug this is usually the same as memory class, I've found situations when memory class returns a higher value (i.e. 24MB) and heap size returns a lower value (i.e. 16MB), and the value realy available for the processs is the lower one.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()  / 1048576L for size in megabytes.

Answer (score 2):

try the following code:

```
      ActivityManager activityManager = = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
      activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
      Log.i("memory free", "" + mi.availMem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite satiscfactory for me, but I've found that [`ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) returns amount of memory allocated for application in megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

start the application and enter the following command

```
    C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb shell dumpsys meminfo "your package name"
```

Comment: But I need to do that programmatically

Comment: i have posted another answer check out

Comment: you can check different other api's for mi also

Answer (score 0):

The `Debug` class provides a lot of useful information about process memory use. You can get information about the Dalvik heap and the native heap. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html